# listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, listbox, selecteditem

what I am trying to do, when an item is selected in listBox1, then listBox2 will populate with options to select from. For example if you pick a white shirt in listBox1 then listBox2 will populate with designs to choose from. I have gone over this a 100 times and from what I have read it should work but it is not working at all. The only thing that works is listBox1 populates with shirt colors. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace EmmasEmbroidery
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listBox1.Items.Add("White");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Black");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Red");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Blue");
    }


    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Enabled = true;
        listBox2.Items.Clear();

        if (listBox1.SelectedItem.Equals("White"))
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add("Peacock");
            listBox2.Items.Add("Palm Tree");
            listBox2.Items.Add("Rose");
        }
        else if (listBox1.SelectedItem.Equals("Black"))
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add("Race Car");
            listBox2.Items.Add("Star");
            listBox2.Items.Add("Moon");
        }
        else if (listBox1.SelectedItem.Equals("Red"))
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add("Palm Tree");
            listBox2.Items.Add("Moon");
        }
        else if (listBox1.SelectedItem.Equals("Blue"))
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add("eacock");
            listBox2.Items.Add("Moon");
        }

        label3.Text = "You have selected a " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " shift";
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.Enabled = false;
        label3.Text = "You have selected a " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " shift with a " + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + " design.";
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Enabled = true;
        listBox2.Enabled = true;

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        label3.Text = "";

        listBox1.Items.Add("White");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Black");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Red");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Blue");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given code is working perfectly fine
[image]
 as far as i know the problem is in the event, you must have copied the code and forgot to add event to the list box.You can add even to listbox by properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Acording MSDN use

```
// Allow the ListBox to repaint and display the new items.
   listBox2.EndUpdate();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.90).aspx